# AvaloniaUI UserControl Binding

Tags: avaloniaui

I have just started using AvaloniaUI and am struggling with even the most simplest of things.
In this case, I want to create a simple custom control (UserControl) with a TextBlock whose Text is set by a bound property.

My UserControl looks like:

```
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
             x:Class="AvaloniaUserControlTest.MyUserControl">
    <TextBlock Text="TemplateBinding Caption"/>
</UserControl>
```

My code-behind is:

```
using Avalonia;
using Avalonia.Controls;
using Avalonia.Markup.Xaml;

namespace AvaloniaUserControlTest;

public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public string Caption
    {
        get => GetValue( CaptionProperty );
        set => SetValue( CaptionProperty, value );
    }

    public static readonly StyledProperty<string> CaptionProperty = AvaloniaProperty.Register<MyUserControl, string>(nameof(Caption), defaultValue: "My Caption");

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

An I am trying to use this control in MainView.axaml like so:

```
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:AvaloniaUserControlTest.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
             x:Class="AvaloniaUserControlTest.Views.MainView"
             xmlns:uc="AvaloniaUserControlTest"
             x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel">
    <Design.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel />
    </Design.DataContext>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Greeting}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <uc:MyUserControl Caption="Test"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

However, I get the error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   AXN0002 XamlX.XamlParseException: Unable to resolve type MyUserControl from namespace AvaloniaUserControlTest Line 18, position 4.  AvaloniaUserControlTest C:\Users\mail\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Projects\AvaloniaUserControlTest\AvaloniaUserControlTest\CSC 1
```

I can't find any specific examples of creating custom controls in Avalonia, the "Authoring Controls" section of the help shows how to register styled properties but does not show a complete example including the AXAML.

What am I doing wrong?

A

Comment: Hi, have you any solutions? I have the same problem ... Best regards Andreas

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this with:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding $parent[UserControl].Description}">
```

See: https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/data-binding/binding-to-controls

Best regards
Andreas